# Is there any way to get all tags available in all feature files of projects in karate?

Tags: karate

We want to avoid report portal's empty launches if passed tag does not available in all feature files. So is there any predefined method or any way in karate to check that passed tag available or not before execution of test cases?

Answer (score 0):

No there is not. Feel free to contribute code.